# Node JS - Get UTC time

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to output the current UTC Time in "hh:mm:ss" like "18:00:25"?

I found [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) with the following code:

```
moment().format('LTS');
```

But I don't know how to use moment.js to output the time in UTC as it only displays my local time like "8:14:50 PM".

If anyone has another simple way to achieve that would be awesome.

Comment: `moment().utcOffset("+00:00").format("LTS")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the time in UTC

```js
moment().utcOffset("+00:00").format("LTS")
```

Answer (score 2):

format **x** provided the time in utc-

moment.utc(Date.now()).format("x")